# Why are some Apache-licensed repositories not in GitHub open dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

I find the repository "SchemaStore/json-validator" in the open GitHub data collection, queryable with BigQuery.

The repository "SchemaStore/schemastore" has the same Apache 2.0 license, but does not seem to be in the open data collection.

I tried:

```
SELECT distinct repo_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files`
WHERE repo_name like 'SchemaStore/%';
```

This only finds "SchemaStore/json-validator", but not "SchemaStore/schemastore".

Answer (score 0):

Not all GitHub projects are included on the BigQuery copy.

They need to have an appropriate license, and `SchemaStore/json-validator` has one.

But there are more criteria.

One is project relevance - we see here `SchemaStore/json-validator` has only 8 stars, and no action during the last 4 years.

I'm not sure when the next list of repos to index refresh will happen, but probably this project won't be included - unless there's a good reason it should.

Comment: Interestingly, the much more popular and current project "schemastore" is not in the collection, while the validator-project is. It's counter-intuitive.

Comment: Right! I was thinking the situation was the other way around. The problem here then is "I'm not sure when the next list of repos to index refresh will happen"

Comment: Meanwhile, schemastore (https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore) has an Apache license and over 800 stars, but it's still not included in the BigQuery results over the GitHub open data